# pip not working on a windows 11 home computer

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm using python 3.10.9 and the pip is not working it gives me a error saying

```
C:\Users\udayv>pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\udayv\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\udayv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please help.

I was trying to install python packages put no pip command would work.
I tried reinstalling python and it still did not work sadly.

Comment: You have a stray/leftover pip.exe that's "wired" to use a Python 3.7 installation. Find out where it is (somewhere on your PATH clearly) and get rid of it. In the meantime you can also run `python -m pip` instead, it does the same thing.

Comment: I guess because i installed tons of python versions. Where do i find the 3.7 pip?

Comment: "I'm using python 3.10.9" versus "python37\python.exe" - You messed up your installations

Comment: You should also check your path system variables since it seems like its looking in the wrong place. You can also try `where pip` or `which pip` (I can never remember which one is right for windows/linux or vice versa) - that might show you "where" the terminal is looking for pip when you run the command.

Comment: Try `where pip`.

Comment: *I guess because i installed tons of python versions* -- this is what python virtual environments are for, so you can stop doing this :)

Comment: I have 4 pips 3.10 3.7 3 and pip

Comment: Then eg rename them "out of the way" until things start to work.